# What causes DeadSystemException with android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

A high number of crashes are reported in connection with a Google map (in lite mode) that is displayed in a recycler view holder.

- Only HockeyApp reports these crashes, Firebase Crashlytics does not.
- The crashes are reported hundreds of times for a relatively smaller amount of users, so it seems to affect a certain type of users.
- Occurs on a range of Android version (7.0, 8.0, 8.1, 9), across a variety of devices (Huawei, LG, Samsung, etc).
- The `DeadSystemException` is always reported in connection with maps, so I would exclude that the device is shutting down for some other reason.
- Tested on Emulator without Google Play Services installed without crash; the map view then displays the expected error message `MyApp won't run without Google Play services, which are not supported by your device.`

The stack trace looks slightly different depending on the device.

For Huawei:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadSystemException
    at huawei.android.app.HwApiCacheMangerEx.getApplicationInfoAsUser(HwApiCacheMangerEx.java:145)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:417)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:409)
    at pt.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17122079@17.1.22 (100306-245988633):3)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.r.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17122079@17.1.22 (100306-245988633):15)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17122079@17.1.22 (100306-245988633):50)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fk.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17122079@17.1.22 (100306-245988633):4)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fm.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17122079@17.1.22 (100306-245988633):4)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
Caused by: android.os.DeadSystemException
    ... 11 more
```

For Samsung:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadSystemException
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:264)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:237)
    at pt.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17122081@17.1.22 (100400-245988633):4)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17122081@17.1.22 (100400-245988633):58)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17122081@17.1.22 (100400-245988633):29)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.h.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17122081@17.1.22 (100400-245988633):62)
    at hj.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17122081@17.1.22 (100400-245988633):4)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:675)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.a(zza.java:7)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf.a(zzf.java:11)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.a(MapView.java:31)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.a(DeferredLifecycleHelper.java:44)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.a(DeferredLifecycleHelper.java:5)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.a(MapView.java:22)
    at com.myapp.myapp.viewholder.MyViewHolder.E(MyViewHolder.java:3)
    at com.myapp.myapp.viewholder.MyViewHolder.A(MyViewHolder.java:6)
    at com.myapp.myapp.viewholder.MyViewHolder.<init>(MyViewHolder.java:159)
    at com.myapp.myapp.activities.MyActivity$18.a(MyActivity.java:55)
    at com.myapp.myapp.adapter.MyAdapter.a(MyAdapter.java:8)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.b(RecyclerView.java:5)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.a(RecyclerView.java:293)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.a(RecyclerView.java:5)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.c(RecyclerView.java:1)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.a(LinearLayoutManager.java:11)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.generateDefaultLayoutParams(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        onDetachedFromWindow(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        onRestoreInstanceState(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        setStackFromEnd(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        smoothScrollToPosition(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        onLayoutCompleted(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        onAnchorReady(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        updateAnchorInfoForLayout(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        updateAnchorFromPendingData(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        fixLayoutEndGap(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        updateLayoutStateToFillEnd(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        scrollHorizontallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        updateLayoutState(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        collectPrefetchPositionsForLayoutState(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        collectInitialPrefetchPositions(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        collectAdjacentPrefetchPositions(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        assertNotInLayoutOrScroll(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        recycleChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        recycleViewsFromStart(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        recycleByLayoutState(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        findFirstVisibleChildClosestToStart(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        findReferenceChild(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        findOneVisibleChild(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        onFocusSearchFailed(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
        prepareForDrop(LinearLayoutManager.java:0)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(LinearLayoutManager.java:44)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.c(LinearLayoutManager.java:394)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.O(RecyclerView.java:38)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.q(RecyclerView.java:37)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:5)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22407)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6579)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22407)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6579)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22407)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6579)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.d(CoordinatorLayout.java:143)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.a(CoordinatorLayout.java:32)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:48)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22407)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6579)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22407)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6579)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22407)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6579)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22407)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6579)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22407)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6579)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:1041)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22407)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6579)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3357)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2826)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8491)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7058)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
Caused by: android.os.DeadSystemException
    ... 84 more
```

The map is implemented like this:

View holder layout (simplified):

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    map:liteMode="true"
    map:mapType="none" />
```

View Holder (simplified):

```
public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private @NonNull MapView mapView;
    private @Nullable Location location;

    public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mapView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.onCreate(null);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(App.getInstance().getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(MyFilter));
    }

    // Called when the view holder is recycled
    public void recycle() {

        mapView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        releaseMap();
    }

    // Called when binding the view holder or by the broadcast receiver
    public void update(@NonNull Location location) {
        this.location = location;

        mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setMapLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        MapsInitializer.initialize(App.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
        map = googleMap;
        map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);

        setMapLocation();
    }

    private void setMapLocation() {

        if (map == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (location == null) {
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
            return;
        }

        LatLng mapLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mapLocation));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mapLocation, 14f));
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    private void releaseMap() {

        if (map == null) {
            return;
        }

        map.clear();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            update();
        }
    };
}
```

What can be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

I've been starting to see this in my App too, but decided, one cannot do much about it. According to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DeadSystemException it means:

> The core Android system has died and is going through a runtime
>   restart. All running apps will be promptly killed.

Actually this rather means your app is in memory often, which probably means, user like it. With my app I started to get these, after starting to interact with Android memory cleanup, i.e. `Application.onTrimMemory()` or `Activity.onTrimMemory()`, which kind of fits, as this should make the (core of) the app remain in memory longer.

This said, unless you consider, that your app itself causes Android system to die, but then you probably have to search elsewhere. Memory leaks, native components etc.

Comment: Do you know perhaps how it's possible to make Firebase Crashlytics ignore it? Trying on the website, it just appears as a new one all the time. Trying to use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler ` and then identifying it (and later call what you got only if that's not it) failed for me for some reason